# How to require .css, .js files inside HTML file in Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin

Is there a way I could do something like this in my html file to require CSS(not inline) and JS (not inline), **I can currently use the same to require image files inside html file.**

1. Requiring image files

> ```
> <img class="img-fluid d-block w-100 img-thumbnail " src='<%=require( "../images/first.png")%>'>
> ```

2. **How can I achieve the same for JS/CSS files ?**

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href='<%=require( "../../../../libs/betaApp/css/style.css")'>
> ```

Comment: use webpack loaders for images, css and js

Comment: @ChandraShekhar, I do use css-loader but looks like it only takes effect when written inside .js file.

Can you provide some more info on how can I achieve this?

Comment: you just write require('<path to the file'>. webpack loader will handle files appropriately based on file extensions.

Comment: I tried doing this in HTML file and it just fails.
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%=require( "../../../../libs/betaApp/css/style.css")'>

Answer (score 0):

You need loaders to do that. You can use CSS-loader and style loader to use the CSS file, file-loader to use the image. Detailed information can be found at;

[Medium Css-Loader Guide](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a)

[File-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)